# getting run time error '1004' by trying to copy a formula

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

I try to copy a formula to a spreadsheet using VBA. I worked with some formulas, but I got suck with this one. What could be a problem?
Thanks.

Here is the code

```
Sub Raznos()
Workbooks("Realization").Worksheets(2).Activate
Range("N2").Formula ="=IF(IF(AND(A1<>A2,M2<>0),K2-L2,"")>0,IF(AND(A1<>A2,M2<>0),K2-L2,""),"")"
End Sub
```

Comment: All your `""` need to be four `""""`

Comment: Change your `""` to `TEXT(,)` to avoid having to deal with double-double-quotes in a string.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little UDF that you can use to deal with quotes in strings:

```
Function QuoteEscape(ByVal rawText As String) As String
    QuoteEscape = Replace$(rawText, """", """""")
End Function
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
Range("N2").Formula = QuoteEscape("=IF(IF(AND(A1<>A2,M2<>0),K2-L2,"")>0,IF(AND(A1<>A2,M2<>0),K2-L2,""),"")")
```